# Пробелов в адресной строке и коде нету ,но Id строки в метод не передается(ошибка HTTP 404)

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть две модели: Satellite и Planet. Схема такая ,что сначала я вывожу на экран  только часть полей  Satellite или  Planet, и у меня напротив каждой строки есть ссылки" Описание" и" Расширенные характеристики", которые ссылаются на соответствующие методы(Данные из  разных таблиц  выводятся в   разные представления , и методы для них находятся в разных контроллерах.), И суть в том ,что в представлении ,которое  выводит на экран  расширенные характеристики, у меня также есть  ссылка " Описание", которая  ссылается на тот же метод ,что и в главном представлении . И при работе с моделью  Planet эта схема  у меня отлично работает. А при работе с  моделью Satellite у меня получается такая история ,что метод DescSatellite вызывается из представления   IndexSatellite , а из  представления  PropSatellite-нет. При этом выходит ошибка HTTP 404, но при   этом  никаких %20 в адресной строке у меня нет, и вообще при заходе на метод DescSatellite из   из представления IndexSatellite картина в  адресной строке та же ,что и  при заходе из  представления  PropSatellite. Я уже нажимал и" Собрать решение ", и "Пересобрать решение ",и "Очистить проект", толку ноль, но при  этом каждый раз выходит сообщение, что у меня"  ошибок: 0". Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Вот код представления  PropPlanet ,которое отлично работает:

```
@{

Layout = null;
  }


  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <title>Расширенные характеристики</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>


        @model SolarSystemThree.Models.Planet

    <h2>Планета № @Model.PlanetId</h2><!-- Принимает значение поступившее в параметр метода  BookView и выводит его на экран.-->
    <p>@Html.Display("DistanceSun")</p><!-- Данные из каждого поля таблицы должны выводиться в отдельный параграф ,чтобы они не выстраивались в одну строку. И не должно быть пробелов между кавычками и именем поля в параметре Display.-->
    <p>  @Html.Display("RotationSun")</p><!-- Данные из каждого поля таблицы должны выводиться в отдельный параграф ,чтобы они не выстраивались в одну строку. И не должно быть пробелов между кавычками и именем поля в параметре Display.-->
    <p> @Html.Display("Rotation")</p><!-- Данные из каждого поля таблицы должны выводиться в отдельный параграф ,чтобы они не выстраивались в одну строку. И не должно быть пробелов между кавычками и именем поля в параметре Display.-->
    <p> @Html.Display("QuantitySatellites")</p><!-- Данные из каждого поля таблицы должны выводиться в отдельный параграф ,чтобы они не выстраивались в одну строку. И не должно быть пробелов между кавычками и именем поля в параметре Display.-->
    <!-- Принимает значение поступившее в параметр метода  BookView и передает его в метод Buy.-->
    <!--<p>Html.ActionLink("Купить", " Buy", "Home", new { id = Model.Id }, null)</p>-->
    <p><a href="/HomePlanet/DescPlanet/@Model.PlanetId">Описание</a></p>
</div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

А вот представление PropSatellite:

```
  @{
Layout = null;
   }

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
 <title>PropSatellite</title>
 </head>
```

```
    @model SolarSystemThree.Models.Satellite

    <h2>Планета № @Model.SatelliteId</h2><!-- Принимает значение поступившее в параметр метода  BookView и выводит его на экран.-->
    <p>@Html.Display("DistanceMain")</p><!-- Данные из каждого поля таблицы должны выводиться в отдельный параграф ,чтобы они не выстраивались в одну строку. И не должно быть пробелов между кавычками и именем поля в параметре Display.-->
    <p>  @Html.Display("RotationMain")</p><!-- Данные из каждого поля таблицы должны выводиться в отдельный параграф ,чтобы они не выстраивались в одну строку. И не должно быть пробелов между кавычками и именем поля в параметре Display.-->
    <p> @Html.Display("Rotation")</p><!-- Данные из каждого поля таблицы должны выводиться в отдельный параграф ,чтобы они не выстраивались в одну строку. И не должно быть пробелов между кавычками и именем поля в параметре Display.-->
    <p> @Html.Display("QuantitySatellites")</p><!-- Данные из каждого поля таблицы должны выводиться в отдельный параграф ,чтобы они не выстраивались в одну строку. И не должно быть пробелов между кавычками и именем поля в параметре Display.-->
    <!-- Принимает значение поступившее в параметр метода  BookView и передает его в метод Buy.-->
    <!--<p>Html.ActionLink("Купить", " Buy", "Home", new { id = Model.Id }, null)</p>-->
    <p><a href="/HomeSatellite/DesсSatellite/@Model.SatelliteId">Описание</a></p>
</div>
 </body>
  </html>
```

Вы можете сказать мне ,в чем проблема? Я сделал еще две вещи.Я сначала  перезагрузил компьютер(Предварительно нажав в студии на" Сохранить все".), а потом скопировал весь код  представления PropSatellite,  потом  удалил весь этот код из этого   представления, а  потом  вставил его обратно. Никакого толку. Я уж не знаю, может у меня проблема не с кодом,  а с сервером на компьютере  или не знаю с чем...Понять ничего не могу. При этом через ссылку " Описание" в главном представлении спутников IndexSatellite и метод, и  представление PropSatellite отлично работают...

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилась такая история, что я не представлял , что  такое вообще может быть... Я закомментировал строку

```
  <p><a href="/HomeSatellite/DesсSatellite/@Model.SatelliteId">Описание</a></p>
```

в  представлении PropSatellite, и скопировал туда ссылку

```
<p><a href="/HomeSatellite/DescSatellite/@b.SatelliteId ">Описание</a></p>
```

из  представления IndexSatellite, а потом поменял переменную счетчика на Model. И у меня все заработало! Я подумал, что это связано с тем,  что в  представлении IndexSatellite после SatelliteId есть пробел, закомментировал эту строку,   которую я  скопировал
 из  представления IndexSatellite ,а потом сделал пробел в изначальной строке 
в  представлении PropSatellite. У  меня опять выскочила ошибка HTTP404 . Потом раскомментировал строку,  которую я  скопировал из  представления IndexSatellite,  а пробел в ней убрал. Но все равно у меня все  заработало...